# IF condition within another IF statement in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a variable (`Practices`) in a table (`CumPractices`) with the following values:

```
0 
4
6
10
0
12
18
0
22
```

I want to create another variable, which has to meet the following:

- when 0, then 0
- when not 0, then subtract the value from the previous row
- when the value from the previous row is 0, subtract from the row before (current row-2)

I could do the loop to meet the first 2 criteria (please see below) but I am struggling to account for the third criteria. Can anyone please help me?

```
blank = cell(n,1)
for i=1:height(CumPractices)
   if CumPractices.Practices(i)==0
      blank{i,1} = 0
   else
       blank{i,1} = CumPractices.Practices(i)-CumPractices.Practices(i-1)  
   end
end
```

Comment: Use [if / elseif / else](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/if.html)? It's all there in docs...

Comment: can there be 2 (or more) zeros? so do you would have to find the pervious non zero or is it just if(i-1)==0 then (i-2)

Comment: Oh, yes, there can be 2 or more zeros, so this is even more complicated that I thought... I will need to find the previous non zero. Do you know how to do this? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Just store the previous non-zero element in a variable and use that in the subtraction:

```
Practices = [0; 4; 6; 10; 0; 12; 18; 0; 22];

blank = cell(size(Practices, 1),1);
prevNonZero = 0;
for i = 1:size(Practices, 1)
   if Practices(i)==0
      blank{i,1} = 0;
   else
       blank{i,1} = Practices(i) - prevNonZero;
       prevNonZero = Practices(i);
   end
end
```

*The output*

```
>> blank'

ans = [0]    [4]    [2]    [4]    [0]    [2]    [6]    [0]    [4]
```

Or if you want to have the value subtracted **from** the previous row (I was confused because of your example), then you can modify the loop as:

```
for i = 1:size(Practices, 1)
    if Practices(i) == 0
        blank{i,1} = 0;
    else
        if prevNonZero ~= 0
            blank{i,1} = prevNonZero - Practices(i);
        else
            blank{i,1} = Practices(i);
        end
        prevNonZero = Practices(i);
    end
end
```

Which will subtract from the previous non-zero element if there were any.

*The output is:*

```
>> blank'

ans =  [0]    [4]    [-2]    [-4]    [0]    [-2]    [-6]    [0]    [-4]
```

Note: I renamed the variables a bit, but it does not matter in term of the solution.